# receive data from arrayBuffer by using XTK

Tags: arraybuffer, xtk

I'm trying to use `XTK` to load `DICOM` files, by using the following code:

```
var _dicom = ['1','2','3']
volume.file = _dicom.sort().map(function(v) {
   return 'data/path/' + v + '.DCM';
});
```

**The Output:**

is an `arrayBuffer`

I would like to know how to read the `arrayBuffer` and render it. I tried `volume.filedata = dataFromArrayBuffer`, but it does not work.

Comment: Is there any method to allow loading arrayBuffer data with XTK js.